# What to call someone who has recently become rich but now his/her attitude has worsen?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm inclined to use parvenu but most meaning suggest about lacking refinement. I'm looking for someone who looks down on the poor. Maybe abusive to the poor.

Comment: The term is nouveau riche, plural. People who are crass and get a lot of money and start behaving badly in all sorts of ways. They often exhibit all sorts of bad attitudes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_riche

Comment: The "newly rich" don't necessarily look down on/abuse the poor.  "Nouveau riche" is (usually) a derogatory term for the self-made wealthy, given to them by "old money" people.

Comment: Probably a more appropriate duplicate candidate (where 'nouveau riche' is given, heavily upvoted, and can no longer be claimed by the most fastidious to fall foul of the 'must be an idiom' constraint) is [idiom/expression for someone who forgets their roots on achieving success](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120850/idiom-for-someone-who-forgets-their-roots/120855#120855).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth feel free to edit. Bear in mind, tchrist's answer  (More formal synonyms of “snob”) is very *very* thorough, nouveau riche being mentioned also, and as an answer, his is by far the most informative and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Toffee-nosed**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/toffee-nosed

"People who are toffee-nosed consider themselves to be better than other people, especially than people of a lower social class: 
He's a toffee-nosed git - take no notice of him!"

Comment: Sure, but this does not go to the heart of the matter: recent acquisition of considerable pecuniary resources.

Answer (score 0):

**nouveau riche**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Nouvo+riche)

> n, pl nouveaux riches  (often plural) a person who has acquired wealth
>   recently and is regarded as vulgarly ostentatious or lacking in social
>   graces